# Build a Function for Autocorrelation

Tags: r, function, autocorrelation

I build the below AR(2) model :

```
# Generate noise
noise=rnorm(200, mean=0, sd=1) 

# Introduce a variable
ma_1=NULL
# Set the value of parameter theta1
theta1=0.7

# Loop for generating MA(1)
for(i in 2:200)
{
  ma_1[i] = 0.1 + noise[i] + theta1*noise[i-1]
}

plot(ma_1, main="MA(1) Model", type = "l", col= "blue")
```

Im trying to **create a function** to calculate the autocorrelation. I want to build a process so for for find that and then make a plot.

Any ideas ?

Comment: There is a function for that: acf(ma_1[-1])

Comment: not an already existed function @G.Grothendieck, i said that i want to build a new one , i want to try it handly ! thanks!

Comment: Check the source code of `acf `byy typing *acf* at the R console or google it -- it's at https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/library/stats/R/acf.R and https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/library/stats/src/pacf.c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the formula for the empirical autocorrelation on Enders' Applied econometric time series (4th edition, page 67):

[image]

where

[image]

Then we just need to write code for it):

```
acf.new = function(y, smax, plot){

  values = numeric()
  for(i in 0:smax){
    values[i+1] = sum((y-mean(y))*(lag(y, i)-mean(y))) / sum((y-mean(y))^2)}
  
  if(plot){
    df = data.frame(Acf=values, Lag=0:smax)

    graph = ggplot(df, aes(x=Lag, y=Acf)) +
      geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0)) +
      geom_segment(mapping=aes(xend=Lag, yend=0))

    plot(graph)}

  return(values)}
```

The plot:

[image]

Endres also gives a formula for the variance of the the acf:

[image]

You can also use this to plot the confidence intervals like `acf` does. If you want, i can write code for it too.

Checking the output (with set.seed(10)):

```
> cbind(acf(ma_1, 23, plot=FALSE)$acf, acf.new(ma_1, 23))

             [,1]        [,2]
 [1,]  1.00000000  1.00000000
 [2,]  0.54446735  0.54446735
 [3,]  0.10622437  0.10622437
 [4,]  0.05674789  0.05674789
 [5,]  0.07363862  0.07363862
 [6,]  0.06474101  0.06474101
 [7,]  0.03218385  0.03218385
 [8,] -0.00330324 -0.00330324
 [9,] -0.07926465 -0.07926465
[10,] -0.10776187 -0.10776187
[11,] -0.11907161 -0.11907161
[12,] -0.09931743 -0.09931743
[13,]  0.01019203  0.01019203
[14,]  0.07401695  0.07401695
[15,]  0.07139094  0.07139094
[16,] -0.02332401 -0.02332401
[17,] -0.14173214 -0.14173214
[18,] -0.12507718 -0.12507718
[19,] -0.04592383 -0.04592383
[20,] -0.05617885 -0.05617885
[21,] -0.12087564 -0.12087564
[22,] -0.05018037 -0.05018037
[23,] -0.01171499 -0.01171499
[24,] -0.10177784 -0.10177784
```

Comment: im finding a difficulty to adjust this to my AR(2) i builded, the struggle is the parameters adjusting i must do @Ricardo Semião e Castro

Comment: To calculate the acf you only need a time series, you don't need any information about the model that created it (you can see that my code only used `y`, not `theta1` nor any parameter). So i don't understand what is your problem

Comment: i make that and here is my mistakes that now i cant get through of them : > # call the function for our purpose, for our AR model y.matrix
> for (k in 1:20)
+ {
+   corr <- autocorr_fnc(y.matrix, k, plot)
+   
+ }
Error in if (plot) { : argument is not interpretable as logical                                                     @ Ricardo Semião e Castro

Comment: The `plot` argument is `TRUE` or `FALSE`, for whether you want to plot the acf graph, or just get its values. The error message says that the `plot` argument you provided isn't true or false.

Comment: Thanks again and i can use this method you create for AR models , especially for AR(2) ?! Right?! Thanks a lot  @ Ricardo Semião e Castro

Comment: Yes, as i said the acf formula for the (empirical) acf of a time series is the same, doesn't matter the model that created the series. The model will interfere in the values of the acf, but not how you calculate it. You're welcome!